# .NET Core SDK Locations was not found on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-2022

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 for Mac [v17.5.4 (build 8)].
And also install .net 6 and .net 7 but the SDK location was not found.

[image]

First I install VS2022 for mac then it is not working then I tried this tutorial [here](https://splashkit.io/articles/installation/mac/languages/dotnet/)
but my installation location is different, folder location: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/bin/dotnet`

```
dotnet --list-sdks
7.0.100 [/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/sdk]
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the result of `dotnet --list-sdks`

Comment: I think the problem is solved now. I just change the path to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/sdk`. Thanks @stuartd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path for Visual Studio 2022 on Mac is causing the issue. VS 2022 can't locate the SDK. As [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd) suggested in the comment `dotnet --list-sdks`, so by replacing the default path with the `list-sdks` path solves the issue.

[image]